# SWTOR Galactic Starfighter Battle

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I was an active player since SWTOR was released and until level 50. I had the role of officer in my guild and then decided to give a break after expansion came.

Now, I decided to continue so I subscribed to the game, have like 7500 cartel coins (don't know what to do with them yet) and took Starfighter quests.

First I played the tutorial, which wasn't sufficient at all. Just flying, doing a couple maneuvers and destroying drones. I wanted to play so I queued for a battle, and boom. I ended up with just a couple of kills, bunch of assists and aimlessly flying around and trying to escape from missiles and enemy Starfighters.

There are probably geared (or whatever you call for Starfighters) or customised players who really do well and their weapons are superior compared to mine (of course).

I always played Space Missions but they were simply against AI and was easy and fun for me.

Now, I am struggling playing this Galactic Starfighter Battle. I want to ask how can I learn it the easiest way, like which ship, crew members, skills to get and use as a starter so I can learn the basics, and then I will be sufficient to advance to new ships and members. I don't want to make my team lose or mad while trying to learn something so I want to learn with "what" and "where" to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your hangar and pick complementary loadouts/companions.  You can be successful with a wide array of them however so there really is no specific advice to give you.  While some of the unlockable things will give you an edge, they are largely "different" rather than "better".  On that note, be sure to try different ship styles and see what suits you.  Taking a look at the list of controls will also give you a better idea than the tutorial did of what you can use to escape/fight/etc.

Just like regular PvP, I don't think there is any substitute for experience.  Everyone had to learn and many still are, so if your teammates get annoyed you should ignore them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TBH I am not a person who can accept whining at games. That's why I wanted a suggestion, but you are right. Playing and experiencing is the most benefical way of getting better. Accepting your answer. But all I wanted was, with which ship and which crew members to start with to understand the mechanics as fast as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I would also say, practise practise and practise. It's not that one ship is better than the other. You can be good with every ship as long as you practise enough with your ship.

On youtube you can find different video's on how to do GSF.

Comment: It would help the answer if you linked to videos you think are especially good. Just pointing to youtube isn't really helpful, I'm sure there are millions of videos.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly found getting to start with the basic strike fighter and it's default loadout helped me when I first started.... I can also say use your ship requisition and upgrade components it helps A LOT